# Save filtered ng-repeat in a new variable

Tags: angularjs, variables, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can I save this filtered ng-repeat in a new variable?

```
   <div ng-repeat="Item in AllItems | filter: { Type: 'test' } | filter: searchByItem as results">
```

I want to do this because I need the length of the filtered array for the pagination.

Comment: You may use a directive. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: Please explain objective in more detail. You are asking a question that can be interpreted several different ways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within `ng-repeat`, when you use `as` to create alias `results` that filtered array will be added to the scope that the element exists in.

Therefore you can use `{{results.length}}` to see the length in view outside of the `ng-repeat` and should be able to pass `results` to other directives